# How to create a template for my school

Tags: header-footer

How can I create a template like the example below?

[image]

Thanks for any response!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Downvoters, a score of -1 is more than enough to show a question needs work.

Comment: Lauro, the last downvote was automatic (it happens when a question is closed usually).

Answer (score 4):

I have to admit I got carried away a bit, and I finished it. So here it is, but please try to post code attempts next time (even partial codes help), or add more information.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}     
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\degree}

\begin{document}
% header    
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[draw=none,fill=green!10] (0,-1) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=north west, align=center,minimum size=3cm, xshift=1cm, yshift=-5mm, text width=3cm,fill=gray] at (current page.north west) {Logo\\3cm x 3cm};
        \node[anchor=north, font=\bfseries,, yshift=-5mm] at (current page.north) (title) {Escola Estadual Professor Valerio de Zevedo Araújo Costa};
        \node[anchor=north west,yshift=-5mm, inner sep=0] at (title.south west) (table) {
        \begin{tabular}{lp{1cm}lp{1cm}c}
            Atividade:                      & & Etapa: 2\textsuperscript{a} etapa   & & Valor: 12 pontos \\
            Disciplina: Matemática          & & Professor: Lauro Costa  & & \multirow{2}{*}{\tikz[baseline,overlay]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=1.8cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=green!10,label distance=-1mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:Nota:}] {};}}\\
            Série: 1\textsuperscript{a} EM  & & Turno: matutino         & & \\
        \end{tabular}};
       \end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{2.5cm}
\noindent Aluno:\makebox[6cm]{\enspace\hrulefill} \enspace N\degree:\makebox[2cm]{\enspace\hrulefill} \enspace Turma:\makebox[3cm]{\enspace\hrulefill} \enspace Data:\makebox[2cm]{\enspace\hrulefill/05/2015}

\end{document}
```